# Connecting multiple ListViews in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a program for Employees and their children. I'm planning that whenever I double click on the employee that is found in listview1, I want to display all his/her children in listview2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour] and also read [ask] and take the time to share some code that you tried.

Comment: Good luck with doing that.  By all means post back when you have actually encountered an issue.

Comment: Sounds like a common ordinary master-detail app.  However, ListViews do not "connect" to anything

Comment: How about if they have grand children? Are you going to need an extra listview3?

Comment: You need to actually ask us a question.  In particular, you need to ask us a specific programming question.